# Custom ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, order-by

Are there other ways to use `ORDER` on my results?

```
20150507094958A DISPOSED        2015-05-07 09:50:00.853 Samuel  MONEY
20150507094958A DISPOSED        2015-05-22 09:25:00.000 Jeff    AUTOMOBILES
20150507094958A DISPOSED        2015-05-26 09:39:00.000 Joel    FIREARMS
20150507094958A DISPOSED-READY  2015-05-29 09:57:00.000 Samuel  MONEY
20150706132447A OUT             2011-10-19 11:25:00.000 Samuel  AUTOMOBILES
20150406110457A OUT             2015-04-02 11:07:00.000 Shane   FIREARMS
20150406105740A OUT             2015-04-06 11:00:00.000 Cordero FIREARMS
20150406105740A IN              2012-03-27 21:15:00.000 Alex    BICYCLES
```

I want to get all the `FIREARMS` on the top and then still order by any other column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. However, this may work for you:

```
select 
    myTable.* 
from myTable
order by (case myCol when 'FIREARMS' then '' else myCol end);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll venture a guess at what you're looking for. I've made the assumption that the table is called `test`, the column which contains the entries for `FIREARMS`, `MONEY`, etc. is called `category`, and of course you have your other columns.

So, with a simplified table and some data defined as

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id integer,
  person varchar(30),
  category varchar(30));

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'Samuel', 'MONEY');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,'Jeff', 'AUTOMOBILES');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,'Joel', 'FIREARMS');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4,'Samuel', 'MONEY');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5,'Samuel', 'AUTOMOBILES');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (6,'Shane', 'FIREARMS');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7,'Cordero', 'FIREARMS');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (8,'Alex', 'BICYCLES');
```

Then, I would write the query as

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY CASE category WHEN 'FIREARMS' THEN '1'
ELSE category END, 
person;
```

which lets you first order to put `FIREARMS` entries at the top, and then sort by a secondary column, where in this case I've chosen `person` as the secondary `ORDER BY` column.

You can use this **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0184b/17)** to confirm it works for your needs.